# Tameness of the trivial extension of a finite dimensional algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

The trivial extension T(A) of a (finite dimensional) algebra A is representation-finite if and only if the algebra A is iterated tilted of Dynkin type.

Questions:

1. Is there a similar classification when the trivial extension of an algebra is tame?
2. Is there a classification when T(T(A)) is tame? It seems this can happens very rarely, one example is A=k, a field.

Comment: This at least seems to happen much more frequently: The paper "On the representation type of certain trivial extensions" by Novoa and de la Pena claims that for a tame one-point extension of a tame concealed algebra by a regular module, then its trivial extension is tame.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Thanks, Ill have a look at it.